# MYSQL - not between all of ranges

Tags: mysql, between

I have two tables in MYSQL where table2 contains ranges of Ids and table1 contains id values. I want to separate table1 ids that is not in table2 ranges. this query :

```
select id
from table1,table2
where table1.id not between table2.start and table2.end
```

will result in ids that not between at least one of ranges. But I want to get Ids that are not between all of ranges.

any idea?

(I dont want to use anti-join because it needs many resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.id between t2.start and t2.end
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i got it right , but if you want to get the ids of table1 that are not between the range of ids of table2, you can try this :

```
select id from table1 
                where table1.id not between 
                 (select min(table2.id) from table2) and 
                  (select max(table2.id) from table2)
```